# Procedure of solving this matrix equation

Tags: matrices

So I have this equation:

[image]

And $n=3$.

What I don't know  is what this 2 signs (before matrix) mean when we have matrix. I'm not mathmatician and I need to make a program that solves this. But first I need to understand how this is solved. Thank you for explanation.

Comment: The signs mean sum $\sum$ (`\sum`) and product $\prod$ (`\prod`). Many would appreciate it (as well as the search engine would benefit from it) if you include the image as a formula into your post via [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A_1,A_2,....,A_k$ are matrices then

$\sum_{i=1}^kA_i=A_1+A_2+...+A_k$ and $\prod_{i=1}^kA_i=A_1\cdot A_2 \cdot...\cdot A_k$

Comment: So if I udnerstand, I need to sum matrice with itself n-times ?

Comment: @Miko Not with itself. It is a different matrix for each different value of $i$.

Comment: Yeah but I always use that one matrix which uses diffrent values for i right?